# How save modified features in server side with java and geotools?

Tags: java, geotools, wfs-t, openlayers-2

I'm developing a gis Application with java. I use Spring 4.0.1 and GeoTools-13-RC1 in server  side and OpenLayers 2.13.1 in client side. In client side, I have a wfs layer and it is as follow:

```
var saveStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Save();

wfs_Layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        version: "1.1.0",
        srsName: "EPSG:4326",
        url: 'point/read',
        featureType: "point",
        featureNS: "http://itsme.opengeo.org",
        geometryName: "the_geom",
        readFormat: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({}),
    })
});
```

`wfs_layer` get all features from server. Sever return features with follow code:

```
try {
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("dbtype", "postgis");
    params.put("host", "localhost");
    params.put("port", 5432);
    params.put("schema", "public");
    params.put("database", "template_postgis");
    params.put("user", "postgres");
    params.put("passwd", "postgres");

    DataStore dataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);

    SimpleFeatureStore pointStore = (SimpleFeatureStore) dataStore.getFeatureSource("point");

    SimpleFeatureCollection featuresCollection = pointStore.getFeatures();
    SimpleFeatureIterator features = featuresCollection.features();

    FeatureJSON fjson = new FeatureJSON();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    fjson.writeFeatureCollection(featuresCollection, writer);

    String json = writer.toString();
    return json;

} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PointController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

The returned features format is as bellow:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [40, 45]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "itsme 1"
            },
            "id": "point.1"
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [35, 40]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name": "itsme 2"
            },
            "id": "point.2"
        }]
}
```

User can edit this layer in client side and with `saveStrategy.save()` send edited features to server. Browser send edited features as follows:
Request Payload:

```
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
    <wfs:Update typeName="feature:point" xmlns:feature="http://iran.opengeo.org">
        <wfs:Property>
            <wfs:Name>the_geom</wfs:Name>
            <wfs:Value>
                <gml:Point xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:4326">
                    <gml:pos>48.694467049643556 35.41594833365911</gml:pos>
                </gml:Point>
            </wfs:Value>
        </wfs:Property>
        <wfs:Property>
            <wfs:Name>name</wfs:Name>
            <wfs:Value>itsme edited</wfs:Value>
        </wfs:Property>
        <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:FeatureId fid="point.2"/>
        </ogc:Filter>
    </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

Now I want to modify featuers in server side. **How do I do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpServletRequest request=...;
org.geotools.xml.parser.Parser parser = new Parser(new org.geotools.wfs.v1_1.WFSConfigration());
TransactionType tt = (TransactionType) parser.parse(request.getReader());
InsertElementType insert1 = (InsertElementType) tt.getInsert().get(0);
```